# Python Package Design And Circular Imports

Tags: python, import, system-design

I'm using Python 3.3.2 to write a package that encapsulates a filesystem. My project looks like this:

```
~/
  python/
    filesystem/
      __init__.py
      file.py
      directory.py
```

With `PYTHONPATH=~/python`.

The problem is, `file.py` needs `directory.py` (for example, for `File.get_directory()`), and `directory.py` needs `file.py` (for example, for `Directory.get_files()`), so I have a circular import.

1. When I use `import directory` in `file.py`, and `import file` in `directory.py`, it only works when my working directory is `filesystem` (that is, when the imports are local).
2. When I use `import filesystem.directory` in `file.py`, and `import filesystem.file` in `directory.py`, it works fine, except the aesthetic nuisance of writing `filesystem.file.File` and `filesystem.Directory.directory` all them time.
3. Curiously, when I use `import filesystem.directory as directory` or `from filesystem.directory import Directory`, I get the circular import error `'module' object has no attribute 'directory'`. My guess is that while `import ...` is lazy, `import ... as` and `from ... import` attempt to evaluate the module and notice the circularity immediately.
4. One way to solve this is to `import filesystem.directory` inside the functions that use it. Unfortunately, many of my methods use it, and importing it inside a class does not seem to work.

This is solvable, of course: sucking it up and writing `filesystem.directory.Directory`; assigning an `__import__` to a global variable in the `__init__` method for all the other methods to use; defining `File` and `Directory` in the same file; and so on. But these are more compromises than solutions, so my questions still stand:

1. How would you design a filesystem, where a file class uses the directory class, and vice versa?
2. And more generally, how would you deal with (or avoid) circular imports?

Thanks.

**UPDATE [03.07.2013]** (Mostly for discussion's sake)

Another solution I came upon is some sort of forward declarations, with empty `file` and `directory` classes in a common header, followed by separate implementations (more like attributes addition). While the resulting design is very neat, the idea is more C++-ish than Pythonic.

Comment: Dealing with circular imports took me a while.  I really had to graph out my modules (by hand) into a tree structure, making sure I was only carrying my dependencies one direction.  Once I started doing that before larger project decisions were being made, it really cut down on the refactoring I had to do later.

Comment: @BlackVegetable - how would you design the described filesystem without circular imports? It looks inherently circular to me, so I would love to hear some outside-the-box alternative designs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a fully-qualified path isn't really a hack; it's probably the proper solution to this particular issue. If you want a shorter name to type out, you could do something like this:

```
import filesystem.directory

class File(object):

   def __init__(self):
       self._Directory = filesystem.directory.Directory

   def foo(self):
       some_dir = self._Directory(...)
```

This also makes it trivial to swap in a mock if you're testing, et cetera.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
These are basically the "sucking it up and writing `filesystem.directory.Directory`" and "assigning an `__import__` to a global variable in the `__init__` method for all the other methods to use" solutions, and I guess the fully-qualified path is indeed the proper solution, but I'm still looking for alternatives, even if only out of academic curiosity.